# custom validation not working.

Tags: cakephp

I'm doing my custom validation in CakePHP model. The problem is that even when it falls on the validation fails and still keeps the record in my database.

```
public $validate = array(
    'fecha' => array(
       'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Debe indicar una fecha y hora.',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ),
       'validar_fecha' => array(
            'rule' => array('validar_fecha'),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'La fecha ingresada no se encuentra dentro de la fecha del evento.'
        )
    ),
);

public function validar_fecha($field){
    $evento = $this->Evento->read();
    if($field['fecha'] > $evento['Evento']['fecha'] && $field['fecha'] < $evento['Evento']['fecha_termino']){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `validar_fecha` is returning `false`?

Comment: Yes, check testing and examples.

Comment: And what does `$this->Model->invalidFields()` return?

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65484 bytes) D:!

Comment: Whoa, I think your problem is something else in you code... please edit your question and paste the controller action that saves the data.

Comment: did you found a solution? I'm having the same issue.